# for loop converter

Tags: c#, for-loop, while-loop, converters

I know there are things like vb to c# converter apps out there, but what I'm looking for is a bit different. I need a converter to help me convert this "for" loop into a "while" loop. Here is the code I'm engineering for my "Integer Factory" (you can see the "for" loop towards the bottom - this is what needs to be converted). I have a few other loops, which is why I need an app for this (preferably wysiwyg). Thanks!

```
int IntegerBuilderFactory(string stringtobeconvertedbythefactory)
{
       string strtmp = stringtobeconvertedbythefactory;

       int customvariabletocontrolthethrottling;

       if (strtmp.Length > 0)
       {
              customvariabletocontrolthethrottling = 1;
       }
       else
       {
              customvariabletocontrolthethrottling = 0;
       }

       for (int integersforconversiontostrings = 0; integersforconversiontostrings < customvariabletocontrolthethrottling; integersforconversiontostrings++)
       {
              return int.Parse(strtmp);
       }

       try
       {             
              return 0;
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
              // Add logging later, once the "try" is working correctly

              return 0;
       }
}
```

Comment: You need an app that refactors "few for-loops" to while loops? Why can't you do it manually?

Comment: Why is that even a for loop if it returns the very first element it converts? Did you attempt to simplify the code in some way or is this actual code you have?

Comment: @R0MANARMY, this is real code that I've been working on for the past few days. I'm making it to streamline conversion processes. I'm using loops to improve security and memory efficiency. I'd be open to any suggestions you may have!

Comment: There's a whole site dedicated to [code reviews](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), you might have more luck posting there and asking for advice.  I am a little curious how you think using loops will improve security though.

Comment: This has to be fake, right?

Comment: @jerry, no need to be rude, I worked hard on this! If you think you can do better I welcome your advice.

Comment: It _really_ took you several days to produce this horribly messy `int.TryParse` implementation, while still delegating all the actual work to the framework? No offense meant, but if that's true, you should probably rethink your job choice... And for a better (reduced IL size, reduced bugs, probably reduced memory size) implementation of that monster above, you should use the version in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Every for loop (`for(initializer;condition;iterator)body;`) is essentially

```
{
    initializer;
    while(condition)
    {
        body;
        iterator;
    }
}
```

Now you can utilize this knowledge to create a code transformation for the refactoring tool of your choice.

By the way, that code looks awful...

```
int IntegerBuilderFactory(string stringToParse)
{
    int result;
    if(!int.TryParse(stringToParse, out result))
    {
        // insert logging here
        return 0;
    }

    return result;
}
```

done.

Comment: Well, I cant necessarily rely on this logic for every instance though. I need an app that takes all considerations into account.

Comment: What _considerations_ are there to take into account? I can't think of any, except for non compilable code...

Comment: The place to be careful is with `continue` statements. In a for loop, the iteration statement will automatically be run. This is not the case for your transformed `while` loop.

Comment: @jerry: indeed, didn't think of that. But this transformation usually doesn't make much sense anyway (except for demonstration purposes), so that shouldn't really matter (because when you need a `for` loop, a `for` loop is the way to go)

Comment: @Nuffin: I agree, I've only come across it when teaching new programmers about `for` loops and `continue` and `break` statements

Answer (score 0):

```
int integersforconversiontostrings = 0;
while (integersforconversiontostrings < customvariabletocontrolthethrottling)
{
    return int.Parse(strtmp);
    integersforconversiontostrings++
}
```